# Invoking observable from another observable

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java

I'm new in RxJava framework. My system use token authentication, when I want to get any response from http request I need to refresh my auth token because of expiration time.

But I got a problem after invoking subscribe method from one observable to another observable

Main class (First observable)

```
service.getPosts(offset,limit, PreferencesUtils.getAccessTokenKey())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnNext(response -> {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new RuntimeException();
        })
        .subscribe(
            feeds -> mView.showNewsFeedItems(feeds.body()),
            error -> {
                Helper.refreshToken();
                service.getPosts(offset,limit,PreferencesUtils.getAccessTokenKey()); 
            }
        );
```

My response is not successful and I need to invoke `refreshToken()` where I can refresh token and save it to `PreferencesUtils`

Helper class (Second observable)

```
service.refreshToken(PreferencesUtils.getAccessTokenKey(), PreferencesUtils.getRefreshTokenKey())
        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe(


// doesnt proceed this part of code
                response -> {
                    PreferencesUtils.saveAccessToken(response.body().getAccessToken());
                    PreferencesUtils.saveRefreshToken(response.body().getRefreshToken());
                },

                error -> Log.d(TAG, "refresh token exception: " + `error.getMessage())`
//

            );
```

When I using debugger, Second observable from Helper class doesn't work properly it doesn't want to proceed this service and has finished immediately on subscribe without any error (definitely it's waiting for finishing all operations from main thread). Because of the subscribe method didn't proceed (wasn't save access token to preferences) I can't execute my `service.getPosts()` function.

Help please! I will be very gratefull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than splitting up the observer chain like that, use the `retryWhen()` operator to respond to a failed token.

```
Observable.just(Boolean.TRUE)
    .flatMap( ignored -> service
                           .getPosts(offset,limit,
                                      PreferencesUtils.getAccessTokenKey()) )
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .doOnNext(response -> {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new TokenException();
    })
    .retryWhen( error -> error.flatMap( f ->
      {
        if ( f instanceof TokenException ) {
          return service.refreshToken(PreferencesUtils.getAccessTokenKey(), PreferencesUtils.getRefreshTokenKey())
            .doOnNext( response -> {
                PreferencesUtils.saveAccessToken(response.body().getAccessToken());
                PreferencesUtils.saveRefreshToken(response.body().getRefreshToken());
            });
        }
        return Observable.error(f);
      })
    )
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe( /* do stuff */ );
```

The `retryWhen()` operator takes an observable that will get whatever exception was thrown upstream. If the exception is a `TokenException`, it will attempt to refresh the token by invoking the observable returned by `refreshToken()` and then saving the result to your preferences.

Edit: Start the observer chain with an observable that can be re-subscribed to without issue. When the access token has to be refreshed, `getPosts()` will be invoked with the new token.

Comment: thank you for respond! it's great logic, but after saving tokens to preferencesUtils it still using outdated token instead of new. so how i can reinvoke getPosts with new access token? thanks

Comment: service.refreshToken locate in other class, so i can't reinvoke getPosts in doOnNext body after saving to Preferences :(

Comment: I added an observable from the start that will properly invoke `getPosts()` with the new credentials.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works! last question on which i can't find the answer. Why i got a compile error in this line of code [ .subscribe(feeds -> mView.showNewsFeedItems(feeds.body())); ] but IDE understand it properly and doesn't show any error. casting 'feeds' to 'Response' doesn't help. when i create a consumer(Observer) everything works fine but i got excessive methods like onError and onUnsubscribe. I will be very appreciate for that

error : cannot find symbol method body()

Comment: My only guess would be that parentheses are in the wrong place. I didn't test my solution for obvious reasons, but getting the parentheses in the right place is one of my favourite errors.